# System is running low graphics mode after uninstalling Unity

Tags: unity

I uninstalled Unity from Ubuntu mistakenly. When I restart the computer I get

> The system is running low-graphics mode

I have tried different commands

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

etc but the problem persists.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` to get it back.